# Unable to install the selected kernel Ubuntu 14.04 from local mirror

Tags: 14.04, kernel, localrepository

We have setup ubuntu local mirror in our environment to do the ubuntu unattended installation, We have setup the local mirror from: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/

Now we are facing the error: Unable to install the selected kernel, kindly check the attached image and assist me to rectify the issue.

Unable to install the selected kernel:

[image: Unable to install the selected kernel]

Comment: I tried with [archive.ubuntu](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/) as install media instead of my local mirror, same issue persist.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (≥100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Are you specifying a proxy server while selecting the mirror? If yes, then use the proper format to specify it:

```
http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@PROXYIP:PROXYPORT
```

Make sure to add the

> http://

or the appropriate suffix in the beginning of the proxy address. For some reason if you miss this then you will get the error which you mentioned. This happened for me and this is the way I solve it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about *how* and *where* to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Comment: A bit more detail would help.